# Jackson completely ignore Jaxb XML related annotations

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, annotations, jaxb

Imagine a situation when you have a model in Java, and you have to serialize it both to XML and CSV.

I am using `Jaxb Marshaller` for XML and Jackson's `CsvMapper` (`ObjectMapper`) for CSV.

Since the formats are slightly different, I want Jackson's `CsvMapper` to ignore `Jaxb` related annotations like `@XmlType` or `@XmlElement`. Because Jackson is getting information/considers xml annotations as well and it leads to wrong result.

How can I do it?

Comment: How do you create `CsvMapper` instance? `Jackson` by default does not recognize `JaxB` annotations. To recognize them `Jackson` requires [jackson-module-jaxb-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations) module.

Comment: no, `Jackson` does recognize `Jaxb` annotations by default, and some of them have higher precedence that its own annotations

Comment: Do you use `Jackson` together with `Spring Boot` or something similar which could automatically register `JAXB` module? How do you create `CsvMapper` object? Could you create a simple example which could reproduce this error?

Comment: hmm...we do use Spring Boot! here's the code for csv mapper:

`CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();`

`csvMapper.findAndRegisterModules();`
`csvMapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY);`
`csvMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(getApplicationZoneId()));`
`csvMapper.setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone(true));`
`CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(clazz)`
`            .withColumnSeparator('|')`
`            .withQuoteChar('"')`
`            .withNullValue("\"\"");`

is there any way i can unregister jaxb module?

Comment: `csvMapper.findAndRegisterModules();` - this line tries to register modules available on class path. You can remove it and `JAXB` module will be ignored. Manually register only this modules you need.

Comment: you were right! you should put it as an answer! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way how you probably create new `CsvMapper`:

```
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
csvMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
```

`findAndRegisterModules` method invokes `findModules` which documentation says:

> Method for locating available methods, using JDK ServiceLoader facility, along with module-provided SPI.

So, probably you have [jackson-module-jaxb-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations) module on class path and this is why `CsvMapper` recognizes `JAXB` annotations.

To fix it, you need to remove invocation of this method `findAndRegisterModules` and register only these modules you needed.